# Euler-Fermat with exponents

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How to solve $6^{(3^{17})}$ mod 11 with Euler-Fermat?

Note: If not possible with Euler-Fermat than with Chinese Remainder Theorem

I know that that they are coprime and I computed $\varphi(11)$, so what are the next steps?

Comment: Since $6^{10}\equiv 1\pmod{11}$, it is useful to know $3^{17}$ modulo $10$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $3^{17} \equiv 3^{16}\cdot 3 \equiv 3 \mod 10$ by the Euler Theorem (as André Nicolas suggested).

Now $6^{3^{17}} \equiv 6^{10k+3} \equiv 6^3 \equiv 7 \mod 11$